# Typed SqlParameter's in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to change the following use of `SqlParameter` into a more typed version

```
private static void Update(int id, string lname)
{
  new RememberEntities().ExecuteStoreCommand(
    @"    UPDATE Users
          SET lname = @lname 
          WHERE Id = @id",
    new SqlParameter("lname", lname), new SqlParameter("id", id));
}
```

For example, I want to be able to write something a long the lines of:

```
private static void Update(int id, string lname)
{
  new RememberEntities().ExecuteStoreCommand(
    @"    UPDATE Users
          SET lname = @lname 
          WHERE Id = @id",
    new SqlParameterString("lname", lname), new SqlParameterInt("id", id));
}
```

Where the second parameter to `SqlParameterString()` would take a string and an `int` in the case of `SqlParameterInt()`. I've tried creating my own by subclassing `SqlParameter`, alas, it is `sealed` so no luck there.

I was wondering what is the recommended EF apprach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create typed factory methods and use only them, but you really can't avoid using `SqlParameter` constructor directly (you'll have this problem even if `SqlParameter` would be not sealed, you can only create your own wrapper method in such case).

Comment: Yes you are correct, factory methods could do the trick. I was hoping for a better alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stored procedure (that returns a scalar value) then using EF 4.0 you can add a 'Function Import' and then you can execute the stored procedure like any C# function.

Comment: Good idea, although I loathe stored procedures :-)